# Why should the generic code compile without constraining T?

Tags: c#, generics

The following code snippet is extracted from Example 10-11 (p. 343) from *Programming C# 5.0*:

```
public static T[] Select<T>(this CultureInfo[] cultures,
                            Func<CultureInfo, T> map)
{
    var result = new T[cultures.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < cultures.Length; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = map(cultures[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I can't figure out how it could get compiled without exposing any information on `T` by applying constraints on it. Specifically, how could the compiler know how many bytes to allocate for the array, given that `T` may not be a reference type, but a value type (i.e., a `struct`)? Also, the semantics of the assignment operation `result[i] = map(cultures[i])` seems to depend on whether `T` is a reference type or a value type.

Comment: "how many bytes to allocate for the array" Does the compiler need to know this ahead of time?

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly the question, but I think that the JIT compiler knows everything you say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key here to understanding this is best expressed as follows:

Firstly, at compile time, a generic method is created, which is simply the IL version of what you've written there in your source. It's typesafe (`map` returns a `T`, and the array cells are of type `T`, so there's no issue there) and everything is fine.

Now, at run time, (conceptually at least) the first time you use `Select<string>`, for example, the JIT compiler at that point creates a new method. Let's call this method `Select__string` (it's actually usually called something like `Select'string` I think, but I don't want you to think that matters for the purposes of this explanation). In that new method, all instances of `T` are replaced with `string`, and so of course in that compiled method everything is easily worked out - assignments, array size allocation, etc.

Next you do `Select<int>` somewhere else. The JIT compiler now creates *a whole new method* which we'll call `Select__int`. And again, all instances of `T` are replaced with `int`, and so again, array size and assignment semantics are easily handled.

The same goes for generic types. When they come to actually be used, `List<string>` and `List<int>` are two completely separate types. This is why .net generics are so easy to write and use.

If this isn't clear, could you give an example of what specifically, in your code above, you think would still need to be known or constrained at compile time?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I seem to have some clue now. Only when you do something that does not apply to all types, e.g., invoking a specialised method, will you ever need to apply any constraint.

Answer (score 9):

There's no dependency between `CultureInfo` and `T` whatsoever. All `T`'s are equally valid, since you handle the "conversion" using your custom `Func<CultureInfo, T>`.

I think you're confused about how generics work in C#. They aren't a compile-time feature (like in Java), they survive all the way to runtime. Only when you actually need a reified generic type is that type compiled, and by that point it already knows what `T` is.

This is of course one of the reasons why C# doesn't have Java's `List<?>`. There's no "common generic type", you're only "delaying" the reification of the types - once you have `List<string>` and `List<int>`, the two are entirely separate types, and only reflection tells you they come from the same generic type.

Comment: But still, if you invoke any method of `T`, a constraint has to be applied. So not all things can be put off to runtime. Is there any simple and general rule as which must be determined at compile time and which may not? Sorry if the question sounds silly. I'm really new to C# :P Or, maybe this deserves a new question itself.

Comment: @Lingxi: Yes, *only* when you start invoking members of T that depend on knowledge of what T exactly is, or when you start assigning values that depend on whether T is a value or reference type. If you don't do any of these in your generic method, then it doesn't matter what T is.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for validating my guess, and I'm really happy that the rule is this simple :)

Answer (score 4):

> Specifically, how could the compiler know how many bytes to allocate for the array,

It doesn't. There's no need for the compiler to know that.

But suppose the `newarr` instruction did need to be given a size in bytes. Then the compiler could simply let the multiplication of the size of the element type and the length of the array be performed at run-time.

> Also, the semantics of the assignment operation `result[i] = map(cultures[i])` seems to depend on whether `T` is a reference type or a value type.

It doesn't depend on that. Regardless of type, an exact copy is made of whatever `map` happens to return. If it's a value type, that means the value gets copied. If it's a reference type, that means the reference gets copied.

Comment: So, the only thing that must be determined at compile time (and thus a constraint has to be applied) is when you invoke a method of `T`?